# Is there a way to use react-native-camera in the background?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm making an app for a project in school. I'm trying to make the face detection feature from the react-native-camera module run in the background in react-native. I have tried using the react-native-android-pip module, but when the application is in pip mode, the face detection feature stops working. Is there an existing module in react-native, or another method to get the face detection feature to run in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You can not run your application in the background in react native because **main thread will pause.**

This is the reason that pip mode fail.

The only solution is to **develop your feature in native** and connect it to your react native app.

Answer (score 0):

Android allow task to run in background (When the app is not fully closed)

For react-native, you will need to build Native module and do some Android native code to perform background tasks (For example, is your app using a camera, press the mid button will not close the camera, PIP)

Android foreground tasks :
https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services

React-native native modules :
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro